# How do I get the type of a webusercontrol?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Normally I would load a control as such then reference it as follows:

```
            if (ctrl is DropDownList)
            {
                formItem = new XElement(@"DropDownList", new XAttribute("name", ctrlName),
                    new XElement("Type", "System.String"),
                    new XElement("displayName", ctrlText),
                    new XElement("length", maxLength),
                    new XElement("key", false),
                    new XElement("required", false)
                );
            }

            formitems.Add(formItem);
```

How do I do the if statement for a web usercontrol?

I'm trying to pass it like:

```
    public void UpdateActiveControl(UserControl ctrl,string formToUpdate,string ctrlName,string ctrlText ,string maxLength)

    {
        List<XElement> formitems = new List<XElement>();
        XElement formItem=null;


            if (typeof(ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                formItem = new XElement(@"TextBox", new XAttribute("name", ctrlName),
                                new XElement("Type", "System.String"),
                                  new XElement("displayName", ctrlText),
```

Comment: Why can't you do this that way? All ASP.Net controls' classes are 100% normal C# classes, so all operators like `is` or `typeof` will work. If you have an `<asp:Label` then `if(xxx is Label)` will work as you assume. Are you having problems with HTML tags like `<select>` or are you trying to do that in JavaScript code?

Comment: please see my comment code above i cnluded how i am trying to pass it ?

Comment: a UserControl is a base type for all your "custom controls" which can have their own "layout" in `ascx` files. They will **never be** a TextBox. They will **contain a** TextBox. You can't check it like that, simply because the **type** of your UserControl will be like "MyUserControlWithATextBox" or "MyAccountLogin"  not a TextBox

Comment: second thing, the syntax for typechecking is not `if(typeof(ctrl) is TextBox)` but it's `if ( ctrl is TextBox )` or either `if ( ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) )`. The latter is rarely used, so don't use it unless you really have to.

Comment: would it be better then to generate the xelement within the control and pass it back as a property then would that be my best course of action

Comment: connecting 1&2 together, you may want to do the typecheck this way: `if ( ctrl is MyAccountLogin )`

Comment: By reading above conversation, i guess - You can enumerate thru each control from your user control and check the type of it by using simple **for loop**

Comment: is it better? that's completely another question. I don't know, because I dont know what you're doing in the larger scope. You'd need to explain what are you doing, why, and how are you trying to do it now, and then maybe we'll be able to tell you what's better or what's easier.